# Netlogo Help - neighbors function

Tags: netlogo

I am a beginner with Netlogo and I am attempting to make a simple model so that when an individual is created, it must be placed in a patch that is neighboring the parent (in one of the 8 spaces). I think I need to use the one-of neighbours command and sprout but I am not sure how to do this.

Currently, I have something this in my code:

```
to birth-death
  set npop count turtles
  ask turtles [
    if random-float 1.0 < dt * r [
      set i random-pxcor
      set j random-pycor
      ask patch i j [set lpop count turtles-here]
      if lpop = 0 [
        hatch 1 [
          set color green
          set xcor i
          set ycor j
        ]
      ]
    ]
    if random-float 1.0 < dt [ die ]
  ]
end
```

Which sets a turtle at a random location, but I am not sure what to write so that when an individual is born it knows to select one of the eight neighbors of the parent site to add a new turtle.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. When a turtle is born (created with the `hatch` command) it is created at the same patch as the parent. So you just need to move it to one of the neighbouring patches from where it already is. Instead of:

```
hatch 1
[ set color green
  set xcor i
  set ycor j
]
```

Use:

```
hatch 1
[ set color green
  move-to one-of neighbors
]
```